# Não estou conseguindo passar um vetor por parâmetro em C

Tags: c, c++, array, parâmetros

Estou tentando passar um vetor por parâmetro para uma função em C, mas estou passando por dificuldades.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void calculafx( x2, *f3, *f4, m){
    int j;
    float fx1=0;

for(j=1; j<=m;j++){
    fx1= fx1+f3[j]*pow(x2, f4[j]);
}
    return fx1;
}

int main(){
    int cont, n , x, i;
    float epsilon, fa, fb, x1, fxx1, a, b;

    printf("Digite o número de termos da função: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    system("clear");
    float f1[n], f2[n];

    printf("Digite o epsilon: \n");
    scanf("%f", &epsilon);
    printf("Digite o primeiro valor do intervalo: \n");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    printf("Digite o segundo valor do intervalo: \n");
    scanf("%f", &b);
    system("clear");

    for(i=1; i<=n; i++){
        printf("Digite o termo %d da função: \n", i);
        scanf("%f", &f1[i]);
        printf("Digite o grau do termo: \n");
        printf("Digite 0 se o termo for uma constante: \n");
        scanf("%f", &f2[i]);
        system("clear");
    }

    do{
        x1= ((a+b)/2);
        fxx1= calculafx(x1, &f1, &f2, n);
        if((fxx1*calculafx(a, &f1, &f2, n))<0){
            b= x1;
        }
        else{
            a= x1;
        }
    }while(abs(a-b)>epsilon);

    fa= calculafx(a, &f1, &f2, n);
    fb= calculafx(b, &f1, &f2, n);
    printf("f(a) é igual a %f e f(b) é igual a %f \n", fa,fb);
}
```

Só que o compilador diz que espera um ")" antes de calculafx(x2, *f3...) e aponta para o *f3. Alguém poderia dizer onde estou errando? Estou usando o gcc para compilar.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você não colocou tipo nos parâmetros e no retorno da função.

Também está errado passar os dois vetores com o operador `&`. Um *array* já é um ponteiro, então esse operador não deve ser usado, já que ele justamente pega o endereço de memória da variável.

Não sei se a formula está correta e provavelmente dá para otimizar mais, mas eu dei uma boa melhorada. Ficou mais fácil de entender o código desta maneira. Sem poder ler fácil é mais difícil achar a solução.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

float calculafx(float x2, float *f3, float *f4, int m) {
    float fx1 = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++) fx1 += f3[j] * pow(x2, f4[j]);
    return fx1;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    float epsilon, fa, fb, x1, fxx1, a, b;
    printf("Digite o número de termos da função: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    system("clear");
    float f1[n], f2[n];
    printf("Digite o epsilon: \n");
    scanf("%f", &epsilon);
    printf("Digite o primeiro valor do intervalo: \n");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    printf("Digite o segundo valor do intervalo: \n");
    scanf("%f", &b);
    system("clear");
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        printf("Digite o termo %d da função:\n", i);
        scanf("%f", &f1[i]);
        printf("Digite o grau do termo: \n");
        printf("Digite 0 se o termo for uma constante:\n");
        scanf("%f", &f2[i]);
        system("clear");
    }
    
    do {
        x1 = (a + b) / 2;
        fxx1 = calculafx(x1, f1, f2, n);
        if (fxx1 * calculafx(a, f1, f2, n) < 0) b = x1;
        else a = x1;
    } while (abs(a - b) > epsilon);
    fa = calculafx(a, f1, f2, n);
    fb = calculafx(b, f1, f2, n);
    printf("f(a) é igual a %f e f(b) é igual a %f \n", fa,fb);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/AXS4fy). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/itnnfxfq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/TypeParamRet.c).

Comment: Estava tentando resolver essa questão usando o VS, mas ele fica dando erro `expression must have a constant value` na declaração `float f1[n], f2[n];`. É coisa do compilador que o VS utiliza?

Comment: @PabloVargas deve estar usando o compilador de C++ que não aceita, ou tem alguma configuração para impedir o uso.

Comment: Sim, imagino que seja melhor usar o um Dev C++ do que o Visual Studio.

Comment: Estranho é que ele está compilando no Coding Ground que usa o gcc, mas no terminal está dando erro.

Comment: @JeffersonBarbosa Que erro?

Comment: "error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode"

Comment: Você está usando um compilador muito antigo, ou está com um padrão ruim e precisa ligar isso com `-std=c99`, você pode resolver isso deixando a declaração da variável fora do `for`. Porém se o compilador é antigo também não deve aceitar declarar *array* com variável. A não ser que o compilador seja manco. Qual compilador e versão está usando?

Comment: É o gcc 4.8.4 no Ubuntu

Comment: Então acho que só faltou usar o `-std=c99` na linha de comando do compilador.