# Lista Encadeada C não insere novo nó

Tags: c, funções, ponteiro, lista, parâmetros

Comecei a fazer um programa de lista encadeada, mas quando uso a função imprimir, ele não estava imprimindo nada, dai descobri que a `LISTA` depois que sai da função insere, ela volta a ter o valor `NULL` e eu não sei porque.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    struct Node {
     int num;
     struct Node *prox;
    };
    typedef struct Node node;

    node* aloca();
    void inicia(node *LISTA);
    void insere(node *LISTA, int val);
    void imprime(node *LISTA);

    int main(void) {
      node *LISTA = NULL;
      inicia(LISTA);
      insere(LISTA, 10);
      insere(LISTA, 20);
      insere(LISTA, 5);
      imprime(LISTA);

      return 0;
    }

    node* aloca() {
      node *LISTA = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
      return(LISTA);
    }

    void inicia(node *LISTA) {
      LISTA = NULL;
    }

    void insere(node *LISTA, int val) {
      node *p1 = aloca();
      node *p2;

      p1->num = val;
      p1->prox = NULL;

      if (LISTA == NULL) {
        LISTA = p1;
      }else {
        p2 = LISTA;
        while (p2->prox != NULL) {
          p2 = p2->prox;
          p2->prox = p1;
        }
      }
    }

    void imprime(node *LISTA) {
      node *tmp;
      tmp = LISTA;
      while(tmp != NULL) {
        printf("\nasfdsdf");
        printf("%d", tmp->num);
        tmp = tmp->prox;
      }
    }
```

Comment: O problema é o retorno do ponteiro mesmo. . Depois vejo se tem outros erros, preciso sair rapidinho.

Comment: Na função `insere` tem um while que me parece suspeito. Você começa a andar pela lista e insere o item logo na primeira iteração. Acho que o correto seria mover aquele `p2->prox = p1;` para depois do while.

Comment: @jHertel Bem observado, mas só otimizou o código, não resolve o problema :(

Comment: @BrunoCasas Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 2):

O código pode ser bem melhorado e simplificado. Mas o problema principal é que não está passando a lista por referência. Mesmo ela sendo um ponteiro precisa passar o endereço dela para que seja refletido  nela o que mexer dentro da função. Aí tem que chamar com [`&`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156278/101).

Também tem a opção de retornar a lista modificada na função. Vou mostrar só o primeiro. Tem um exemplo do segundo em [Não estou conseguindo passar um vetor por parâmetro em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185068/101)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int num;
    struct Node *prox;
} Node;

void imprime(Node *lista) {
    Node *tmp = lista;
    while (tmp != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", tmp->num);
        tmp = tmp->prox;
    }
}

void insere(Node **lista, int val) {
    Node *node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node->num = val;
    node->prox = NULL;
    if (*lista == NULL) {
        *lista = node;
    } else {
        Node *atual = *lista;
        while (atual->prox != NULL) {
            atual = atual->prox;
        }
        atual->prox = node;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    Node *lista = NULL;
    insere(&lista, 10);
    insere(&lista, 20);
    insere(&lista, 5);
    imprime(lista);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/I4JCZC). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/icrdtsjd-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/PointerByReference.c).

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, resolveu o problema :D

Comment: @BrunoCasas dê uma olhada no [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Altere o código para:

```
 void insere(node **LISTA, int val) {
      node *p1 = aloca();
      node *p2;

      p1->num = val;
      p1->prox = NULL;

      if (*LISTA == NULL) {
        *LISTA = p1;
      }else {
        p2 = *LISTA;
        while (p2->prox != NULL) {
          p2 = p2->prox;
        }
         p2->prox = p1;
      }
    }
```

Você estava usando `p2->prox = p1;` a cada iteração no teu while, e deve retornar um ponteiro para ponteiro ja que a função é void.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda